# Module not found in django

Tags: python, django, import

I have a django project with the following structure:

```
game_app
  lobby_app
    __init__.py
    lobby_serializers.py
  user_app
    __init__.py
    user_serializers.py
  manage.py
```

When I try to import user_serializers/UserSerializer into lobby_serializers.py with
from game_app.user_app.user_serializers import UserSerializer

I receive module not found from Python.

Why is that?

I've tried all kinds of import statements, relative, absolute, etc. and I always receive module not found or relative import beyond top level package error.

Comment: How are you putting `game_app` on your Python path? Usually you'll need to either rely on it being in your CWD or you'll need to install your project as a distribution package.